# getting issue while logging "Parent pipeline used these runtime parameters" in yaml

Tags: logging, parameters, triggers, schedule, azure-pipelines-yaml

while I'm triggering a azure pipeline manually I'm getting all logs as mention in the snapshot while in scheduled run I'm not getting the highlighted logs.
Here is the snapshot.
[Snapshot of log details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVucI.png)

in this case I think the logs must be same but I've no idea why its different, in manual case i'm getting three logs while in scheduled I'm getting only one log.